# Make entity_types translatable

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm new to Drupal and a little bit confused.

I want to make entity_types translatable by using the i18n module. Content types are already perfectly translatable, but I couldn't find out how to duplicate that. I managed to use the hook_i18n_string_info() to kind of register entity_type to the translation module this way:

```
$groups['entity_type'] = array(
  'title' => t('Entity Type'),
  'description' => t('Translatable entity types'),
  'format' => FALSE,
  'list' => TRUE,
);
```

When I do this, under "Administration -> Configuration -> Regional and Language -> Translate Interface -> Overview" I now see the column "Entity Type" with "n/a" at the target language and "0/0" at the default language.

After switching to the tab "translate", under "Limit search to" I can select "Entity Type", but nothing is found (the message "No strings available." is displayed).

After switching to the tab "strings", I can select "Entity Tape", but after clicking on "refresh strings" it says "Cannot refresh strings for Entity Type." (5/5 items were processed, I suppose these are the standard entity types?!).

What I tried so far but without any effect was the hook_i18n_object_info():

```
$info['entity_type'] = array(
  'title' => t('Entity Type'),
  'class' => 'EntityType',
  'key' => 'id',
  'base path' => 'admin/structure/entity_type/edit',
  'placeholders' => array(
    '%entity_type' => 'name',
  ),
  'edit path' => 'admin/structure/entity-type/%entity_type/edit',
  'translate tab' => 'admin/structure/entity-type/%entity_type/translate',
  'string translation' => array(
    'textgroup' => 'entity_type',
    'type' => 'type',
    'properties' => array(
      'label' => t('Label'),
    ),
    'translate path' => 'admin/structure/entity-type/%entity_type/translate',
  ),
);
```

I did not find anything useful about this topic but this link: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-jun-01/challenges-satisfy-translation-needs-drupal-and-how-do-you-code-it-now

I frequently emptied the cache with "drush cc all" and used "drush fra" also.

Thanks in advance!